# Efeito Chanfro[Bevel] em textos do PS em CSS

Tags: html, css, webdesign, photoshop, psd

Estou enfrentando um problema que acredito ser comum entre **Designer** e **Dev/frontier/webdesigner** ou por falta de comunicação na hora da criação ou por falta de conhecimento técnico do desenvolvedor para aplicar a técnica.

Estou produzindo o desenvolvimento de um Layout que está montado em um PSD que entre os elementos/camadas contidos no mesmo, há textos com efeitos (aqueles que podem ser habilitados e configurados no "*Opções de Mesclagem*"). Alguns dos efeitos podem ser replicados facilmente no CSS, preservando a qualidade na utilização dos elementos e seus respectivos efeitos, porem estou enfrentando problemas ao replicar o Efeito de "*Chanfro e Entalhe*" (ou nas versões em Inglês, "Bevel & Emboss") nos textos.

O efeito em questão que estou tendo dificuldade é o Chanfro/Bevel. Acredito que em poucas palavras, este efeito aplica uma sombra interna ao elemento na mesma cor, porem em um tom mais escuro ou claro acompanhando o posicionamento da "Luz Global".

Com esse efeito, o texto fica mais ou menos assim:

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como aplicar em CSS?

Em *box-shadow* poderia utilizar o atributo *inset*, porem está já não pertence aos parâmetros de *text-shadow*.

A solução Paliativa está sendo utilizar imagens(png ou svg).
Acredito que outra solução seria gerar uma outra fonte com essas características já pré-estabelecidas.

Obs¹: Por hora, nos próximos trabalhos, solicitei para o Designer tentar ao máximo não utilizar este efeito em textos;

Obs²: Para os designers de plantão, obviamente meu colega não aplicou este efeito tão amadoramente quanto apliquei no exemplo acima.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir do conteúdo [dessa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28413382/2932525) é possível fazer um efeito aproximado com a propriedade CSS `background-clip: text`.

Apesar de funcionar em alguns navegadores, esse valor da propriedade não está especificado [na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip), então você deve avaliar o seu uso.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #00c;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<h1>Texto de Exemplo</h1>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, irei explorar melhor está funcionalidade.